# Decomposition of $_1F_2(1+n;1,2+n;x)$

Tags: special-functions, closed-form

I am looking for a way to decompose $_1F_2(1+n;1,2+n;z)$ for $n\in\mathbb{N}$ into either Bessel J functions or regularized confluent hypergeometric functions $_0\tilde F_1(b(n),z)$. Mathematica seems to be able to do the decomposition for $n=1,2,3,4$ but I am trying to get a closed form for any $n$. I have looked through [Wolfram's functions site](http://functions.wolfram.com/HypergeometricFunctions/Hypergeometric1F2/) but have been unsuccessful in my search. This would be useful because numerical routines can deal with Bessels much faster than hypergeometrics.

Comment: This seems relevant: [Wolfram Functions link](http://functions.wolfram.com/HypergeometricFunctions/Hypergeometric2F1/03/06/07/02/0004/)

Comment: Is it really $_1F_2$ or is it $_2F_1$?

Comment: It is ${_1F_2}$.

Comment: @andre Yes it is really $_1F_2$.

Comment: I believe that a simple relation can be obtained by careful use of https://oeis.org/A068424 .

Answer (score 1, accepted):

While I've studied this hypergeometric series I've observed that

$${_1F_2}\left(\begin{array}c1+n\\1,\,2+n\end{array}\middle|\,x\right)=\sum_{k=0}^{2n}\frac{(-1)^k\,c_{n,k}\,I_{k+1 \operatorname{mod} 2}\left(2\sqrt x\right)}{x^{n-\frac k2+ \frac 12}},$$

with

$$c_{n,k}=\frac{n!(n+1)!}{\left\lfloor\frac k2 \right\rfloor!\left\lfloor\frac k2 + \frac 12 \right\rfloor!}$$

coefficients. Here $I_\alpha(x)$ denotes the [modified Bessel function of the first kind](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bessel_function#Modified_Bessel_functions_:_I.CE.B1.2C_K.CE.B1).

Comment: You've found a nice closed form relation. I'm still hoping that something a bit simpler is found though!

Comment: By the way there are a lot of related sequences. If you write the $c_{n,k}$ coefficiencts into a triangle, then the columns of the triangle are in order: [$\mathrm{A000027}$](http://oeis.org/A000027), [$\mathrm{A002378}$](http://oeis.org/A002378), [$\mathrm{A011379}$](http://oeis.org/A011379), [$\mathrm{A047928}$](http://oeis.org/A047928), [$\mathrm{A208139}$](http://oeis.org/A208139), $\dots$

Answer (score 1):

I have found a somewhat simple relation based on the triangle of falling factorials, reading by rows ([A068424](https://oeis.org/A068424)). We have $$_1F_2(1+n;1,2+n;z)=\sum_{k=1}^{n+1}\begin{pmatrix}
  n+1  \\
  k
 \end{pmatrix}k!(-1)^{k+1}\,_0\tilde F_1(;1+k;z),\,n\geq 0 \\
=\sum_{k=1}^{n+1}\begin{pmatrix}
  n+1  \\
  k
 \end{pmatrix}k!(-1)^{k+1}(-z)^{-k/2}J_k(2\sqrt{-z}),\,n\geq 0.$$

Now we can use the recurrance relation to get it all in terms of 1 or 2 bessels/confluents in order to reduce computation time. By [Wolfram's Functions](http://functions.wolfram.com/HypergeometricFunctions/Hypergeometric0F1Regularized/17/01/02/02/) we have $$_0\tilde F_1(;b;z)=z^{-m}(2-b)_{m-1}\left ( \, _0 \tilde F_1(;b-m-1;z)\sum_{j=0}^{m-1}\left [ \frac{(m-j-1)!(-z)^j}{j!(m-2j-1)!(2-b)_j(b-m)_j} \right ]\\+(1+m-b)\,_0\tilde F_1(;b-m;z)\sum_{j=0}^{m-1}\left[\frac{(m-j)!(-z)^j}{j!(m-2j)!(2-b)_j(b-m-1)_j} \right ] \right ) \\
=z^{-(b-2)}(2-b)_{b-3}\left ( \, _0 \tilde F_1(;1;z)\sum_{j=0}^{b-3}\left [ \frac{(b-j-3)!(-z)^j}{j!(j+1)!(b-2j-3)!(2-b)_j} \right ]\\-\,_0\tilde F_1(;2;z)\sum_{j=0}^{b-3}\left[\frac{(b-2-j)!(-z)^j}{(j!)^2(b-2-2j)!(2-b)_j} \right ] \right ),\,b\geq 3$$

Comment: I don't really think that this form is more simple. It's okay that in my solution you have to calculate $4n+4$ factorial number and in yours the number of factorials only $2n+2$, but in my solution there are only $2$ different Bessel functions, in yours there are $n+1$ Bessel functions in the expression.

Comment: @user153012 . I agree, in terms of computation your solution is probably faster.

Comment: It looks like, using the recurrence relation, my expression becomes yours.

Comment: Yes of course the two expressions are equivalent.